# Store an array of images from a server call?

Tags: android, image

I'm making my own adapter to fill list views with an image and some text.  I want the adapter to take in 3 parameters (`Context`, `String[]`, and some image array).

However, I am unsure how to set this class up.

If I make server calls to get the images, is there a good way to store them in an array to pass into the adapter?

Comment: If you try to store a bunch of images in memory you're probably going to crash the app unless they're very small.  If they're just little thumbnails you might be ok but if they're larger you will probably need to save them to storage and pass an array of file names or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a custom class for your adapter to display.

```
class AdapterData {
    String text; 
    String url; // Some image url from a web service

    // Or, if you are loading images from disk
    // int resourceId;

    public AdapterData(String s, String url) { 
        // TODO
    }
}
```

Then you implement a `ArrayAdapter<AdapterData>`

**Note** this is for a `ListView`, not a `RecyclerView` adapter

```
class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AdapterData> {
    private ArrayList<AdapterData> mData;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyAdapter(Content c, ArrayList<AdapterData> data) {
        super(c, 0, data);
        this.mContext = c;
        this.mData = data;
    }

    // TODO: Implement getView
}
```

When you get your results from your web service, build an ArrayList and initialize the adapter with that list.